# Create Docker container for Angular CLI

Tags: docker, dockerfile, angular-cli

I am trying to create a Docker container for Angular CLI.  My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM node:8.1.4
RUN npm install -g @angular-cli
```

However, Docker does not like the `@` character in the run command.

```
npm info using node@v8.1.4
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "@angular-cli": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
```

I also tried to escape the `@`, but same error.

```
FROM node:8.1.4
RUN npm install -g \@angular-cli
```

The Angular CLI docs say I need the `@` character.  How can I do this in a Docker `RUN` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo in there. According to the documentation, Angular CLI should be installed as follows:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Notice how you have used `-` instead of `/`.

The error is from npm, not Docker, which is what tipped me off.